# Can't boot windows 10 after Ubuntu installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive

I'm new to ubuntu. Recently I installed ubuntu. Hard drive partitioning for ubuntu was done during the installation process. Now I can't go to hard drives giving an error message that it can't mount hard drives. I went through online help and it was said to restart windows after booting from GRUB. But from GRUB even though I select windows 10 loader windows does not boot. Basically I have two problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix) and [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the boot-repair tool. Open terminal and type the following to install.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

Then run boot-repair by typing `boot-repair` in terminal and then select the `Recommended repair` option. When repair is finished, note the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper, then reboot and check if you recovered access to your Windows, if not comment with the URL.

For more details visit https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair